# Wordpress/Disqus visual glitch: blank space

Tags: css, wordpress, disqus, clearfix

There's a huge blank space between the WP Disqus official Plugin comments and its social bar (Like/Dislike/Settings), as shown in this screenshoot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/IodzO.jpg
Coincidentally, the blank space ends where the right sidebar ends.
As Firebug shows, there's something in disqus_thread or disq-content that causes this glitch.
I tried deleting my personal style.css clearfix code or just deleting height:0, but nothing changed

```
.clearfix:after {
    content: ".";
    display: block;
    height: 0;
    clear: both;
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

You can see it "live" on any post in my blog (ie. http://www.flapane.com/blog/2010/11/rai-rinuncia-ad-acquistare-diritti-champions-league/ ), just between the post itself and the Disqus comments.

Any hints? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed.
Disqus has a solution for cases like this:

```
#dsq-content { overflow:auto !important; }
```

However it shows a vertical scrollbar, so I changed it to:

```
#dsq-content { overflow:hidden !important; }
```